# How to display and link an certain attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display all the topics that are being discussed on my application, so I created a dropdown menu (btw if there is a better way of doing this please feel free to share it):

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="topic_category">Category</label>
          <select id="topic_category" name="topic[category]" class="form-control">

            <option>Art</option>
            <option>Business</option>
            <option>Books</option>
            <option>Charity</option>
            <option>Coding</option>
            <option>Cooking</option>
            <option>Dance</option>
            <option>Design</option>
            <option>DIY</option>
            <option>Engineering</option>
            <option>Fashion</option> etc...


          </select>
      </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to create links to each single category and also display how many topics are active through something like

----- Edit 1 -----

what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" style ="padding-top: 10px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">Topics</h4>
      <link_to project.category(Art)> (project.category(art).count)
  </div>
```

I know that is wrong but is the closest I get to explaining what I'm trying to achieve

---- Edit 2 -----

So I'm still trying to get it right, this is probably because I'm a newbie. So following your answers I implemented the code which looks something like this.

static_pages controller.

```
 def home
    if logged_in?
      @user = current_user
      @topics_count = Topic.group(:category).count
      end
    end

    def categoryselection
      category = params[:category]
      topics = Topic.where(category: category)

      render json: { success: true, Topics: topics }
    end


def help
end

def about
end

def contact
end

end
```

home view

```
   .......
    <% if logged_in? %>

  <div class="row">
        <%= render 'shared/sidebar_right' %>
      <div class="col-md-8" style = "align-content: right">
        <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
      </div>

  </div>

<% else %>
 .....
```

Sidebar_right view

```
            ......
            <div id='topics'>
            <% @topics_count.each do |topic, count| %>
            <a class ='project-link' href='topic_path?category=<%= topic %>'> <%= topic %> (<%= count %>)</a>
            <% end %>
            ......

<script type>

$('#topics').on('change', '.topic-link' function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(e.currentTarget).val();
  var queryUrl = $(e).href + '?category=' + category;
  $.get(queryUrl, function(resp) {
    if (resp.success) {redirect_to topic_path 
      // select the div or whatever node on the DOM you are displaying the result, and change it.
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Topics Controller

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

.....

def index
end

def show
  @user = current_user
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])

end

.....
```

The error I'm getting is no routes match [GET] topic_path, and I've checked on my routes and it does exit it actually refers to "show", is this happening because the page I'm using is home rather than the topics page?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean by link an onclick/onchange event? HTML select elements cannot contain a link.

Comment: @Fallenhero thanks for your answer, so what I meant was to have a list with all the possible topic categories, with links to those topics (depending on their categories). This is to be displayed on my home page, so people can click on them and only see those topics categories they have clicked on.

Comment: just pass it in as a query param and create a `where` query should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your new edit

In the controller:

```
def index
  @topics_count = Topic.group(:category).count
  # this will give you something like this { 'Art' => 10, 'Business' => 15' }
end
```

on the html page:

```
<div id='topics'>
  <% @topics_count.each do |topic, count| %>
    <a class='topic-link' href='topic_show_url?category=<%= topic %>'> <%= topic %> (<%= count %>)</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You don't need to (and shouldn't) load all the topics because you are just showing the count, and at large scale, loading the entire table will likely crash your site.

#### This will take care of your second request, showing the topic the user picks when the link is clicked.

on the page, send ajax request when user select one of those options.

```
$('#topics').on('click', '.topic-link', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(e.currentTarget).val();
  var queryUrl = $(e).href + '?category=' + category;
  $.get(queryUrl, function(resp) {
    if (resp.success) {
      // select the div or whatever node on the DOM you are displaying the result, and change it.
    }
  });
});
```

in the controller

```
def you_define_this_method
  category = params[:category]
  topics = Topic.where(category: category)

  render json: { success: true, topics: topics }
end
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have added an Edit 1, the code you proposed does it a similar thing?

Comment: @Eltorero1992 my answer would allow you to show topics of different category by updating the current page without redirecting the user to a different page. similar to how a filter in most ecommerce website would do. Then constructing the link to the topic is simply either returning the url from the controller, or just use the id, and construct it in javascript.

Comment: @Eltorero1992 added edit that will do what you need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks! but now I having another problem as I need to modify show in the topics controller any so to display only those project, any ideas?

Comment: @Eltorero1992 just rolled back my answer. the second part should do it.

Comment: I'm still trying to get it right.. but it doesn't work please see my edit 2!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a link inside your `<option>` tag... ie.

```
    <option><a href="www.something.com">Art</a></option>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is something like I show in Edit 1